How to use vuex in vite
Now I have a problem using vuex in vite. My problem is caused by when I run dev and it gives an error vuex unknown but when I press save file CRUD/get.js it doesn't error. It only gives an error when. run dev I don't know how to fix this.

This is the vue file that calls the getter. establishment.vue
 async mounted() {
    await this.$store.dispatch("get/getProvince");
    await this.$store.dispatch("get/getDistrict");
    await this.$store.dispatch("get/getLocality");
    await this.$store.dispatch("get/getCorporation");
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      _getProvince: "get/_getProvince",
      _getDistrict: "get/_getDistrict",
      _getLocality: "get/_getLocality",
      _getCorporation: "get/_getCorporation",
      _inputCorporation: "exec/_inputCorporation",
    }),
  },

store/index.js
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import Main from "./modules/Main";
import MainMenu from "./modules/menu/MainMenu";
import get from "./modules/CRUD/get";
import post from "./modules/CRUD/post";
import exec from "./modules/CRUD/exec";

export const store = createStore({
  modules: {
    Main,
    MainMenu,
    get,
    post,
    exec
  },
});

CRUD/get.js
const state = () => ({
  Corporation: [],
  Province: [],
  District: [],
  Locality: [],
});
const getters = {
  _getCorporation: (state) => {
    return state.Corporation;
  },
  _getProvince: (state) => {
    return state.Province;
  },
  _getDistrict: (state) => {
    return state.District;
  },
  _getLocality: (state) => {
    return state.Locality;
  },
};
const actions = {
  async getProvince({ commit }) {
    try {
      const response = await window.Axios.get(`${window.api}get/getProvince/`);
      await commit("getProvince", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
  async getDistrict({ commit }) {
    try {
      const response = await window.Axios.get(`${window.api}get/getDistrict/`);
      await commit("getDistrict", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
  async getLocality({ commit }) {
    try {
      const response = await window.Axios.get(`${window.api}get/getLocality/`);
      await commit("getLocality", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
  async getCorporation({ commit }) {
    try {
      const response = await window.Axios.get(
        `${window.api}get/getCorporation/`
      );
      await commit("getCorporation", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
};
const mutations = {
  getProvince(state, payload) {
    state.Province = payload;
  },
  getDistrict(state, payload) {
    state.District = payload;
  },
  getLocality(state, payload) {
    state.Locality = payload;
  },
  getCorporation(state, payload) {
    state.Corporation = payload;
  },
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};

vite.confog.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
const plugins = [vue()];

export default defineConfig({
  plugins,
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vuex: "vuex/dist/vuex.esm-bundler.js",
    },
  },
});


please simply copy/paste errors into your question rather than full screen screenshots, see here for why.

regarding your problem, store.dispatch is for dispatching actions, not getters, hence the error "unknown action type".  you're already setting up computed properties for your getters which, according to the documentation, is the correct way to use getters.  you should simply remove your mounted code.
